# Outlook Query Builder ( OR ) AND ( OR )

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2016

Using Outlook instant search bar, this works fine:

`(from:domain1.com OR from:domain2.com OR from:domain3.com) AND (contents:word1 OR contents:word2)`

But I need to save it as a Search Folder. I have Outlook Query Builder installed.

I'm guessing it should look something like this, but moving things up and down, I can't even get Query Builder to make this:

| AND |
| --- |

| OR |
| --- |
| from:domain1.com |
| from:domain2.com |
| from:domain3.com |

| OR |
| --- |
| message:word1 |
| message:word2 |

What happens is every time I move everything out of the "AND" clause, it collapses rather than nesting.  So, my question is how do I move things around to force it to nest properly?  Assuming this is even the right way to nest them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you create the search folder as shown in the figure below?

[image]

If so, you just need to add four criteria to list and then choose the one > click Move Done, then the one will in a separate group.

[image]

[image]

Then you just need to continue add another two criteria. Hope to help you!

Comment: Thank you so much.  So very clunky, but with your help, I'm able to manipulate it properly.  I now have another issue that it's not finding what it's supposed to, but at least I now have the ability to play around with it.